# Why does the background color of my CheckBox change when ListView is touched?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, background-color

I have a custom `ListView` in which each `row.xml` looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/star_listed"
    style="?android:attr/starStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:contentDescription="@string/question_img_cd"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listTitles"
    style="@style/ListTitles" />
```

Everything works fine except that when I press anywhere on the `ListView`, the background of the `CheckBox` changes to black (instead of remaining white). It happened before to my `TextView` as well until I set its background color to white.

[image: row.xml]

If I changed the ´CheckBox´ background to white, or even tranparent, it disappears.

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html

Comment: My custom `ListView` is working fine. I don't see anything related to my problem in your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but that probably happens because you use the default style attribute for the star(`?android:attr/starStyle`) which has a transparent background(I'm not sure) and you see the underlying black row color. Try to set the the white color for the parent `LinearLayout` in the row instead of setting the color for each `View` in the row.

Comment: You again! I had set it to the ´ListView´, but not the  ´LinerLayout´. Thanks. That was it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background checkbox on style xml file on your project resources in transparent (or) set the listview background color!

Welcome!

Comment: Hi @Dinesh, my question is about the color of the `CheckBox` only, which should be solved on xml attributes. The logic of the custom `ListView` is working fine.